# How can I find the version of the Fedora I use?

Tags: linux, fedora

```
sudo find /etc | xargs grep -i fedora > searchFedora
```

gives:

```
/etc/netplug.d/netplug: # At least on Fedora Core 1
...
```

But see the Fedora version in the `/etc/netplug.d/netplug` file. Is it serious?

Comment: Should be migrated to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fuser97381: That is not true. Curatorship is important and curating does not take place through Google.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit False. Curation (not curatorship, wtf) might be important for the owners of the sites who are making a living off the labour of content creators, but users find information through google, which indexes both sites, so it doesn't matter to them.

Comment: @Fuser97381: I know it doesn't matter to them, but you insinuated that it does not matter at all, which _is_ false.

Comment: `cat /etc/fedora-release/`

Answer (score 190, accepted):

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Or  `cat /etc/fedora-release` as suggested by @Bruce ONeel

Comment: Thanks, Indeed is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 5)

Comment: However, this won't work if anyone's changed the login banners … I typically edit mine, and so, it seems, do many (most) corporate IT departments... :-(

Comment: That's a wrong answer. The answer of @BruceONeel should be accepted as the correct one

Comment: Doesn't work in fedora 26. However Bruce's answer works.

Comment: ```\S
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

Comment: /etc/fedora-release seems to be the good one, unless I have Fedora version "\S
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)" LOL

Answer (score 160):

You can also try `/etc/redhat-release` or `/etc/fedora-release`:

```
cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 7 (Moonshine)
```

Comment: `cat /etc/redhat-release` works for me too, but the better is `cat /etc/os-release` which really gives detailled information.

Answer (score 60):

The proposed standard file is `/etc/os-release`. See http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html

You can execute something like:

```
$ source /etc/os-release
$ echo $ID
fedora
$ echo $VERSION_ID
17
$ echo $VERSION
17 (Beefy Miracle)
```

Comment: I never thought of using `source` to load the variables, I always tried to parse the values. Brilliant!

Answer (score 25):

The simplest command which can give you what you need but some other good info too is:

```
hostnamectl
```

Comment: This is definitely the most convenient answer and also shows the bitness. Nice!

Answer (score 22):

You could try

```
lsb_release -a
```

which works on at least Debian and Ubuntu (and since it's LSB, it should surely be on most of the other mainstream distros at least). http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/sourceforge/l/ls/lsb/lsb_release-1.0-1.i386.html suggests it's been around quite a while.

Comment: It's in package `redhat-lsb`, which wasn't installed by default on my box at work, at least (Fedora 15) (corporate IT fail?) but was on my home Fedora 16 box. (Not sure if it's a default package or not)

Comment: Or `lsb_release -d` for a shorter output.

Answer (score 15):

```
cat /etc/*release
```

It's universal for almost any major distribution.

Comment: This is very true!  This command can be used on practically any Linux distro.

Answer (score 7):

These commands worked for Artik 10 :

- cat /etc/fedora-release
- cat /etc/issue
- hostnamectl

and these others didn't :

- lsb_release -a
- uname -a

Answer (score 6):

What about `uname -a` ?

Comment: That gives the version of the Linux kernel, which might be from a different version of FC or RHEL.  It's debatable if the OS remains that reported by /etc/issue if you change the kernel, but there you are. :)

Comment: uname -a does not give the distrib but kernel, network, machine, processor, hardware and GNU/Linux for operating system! That is not enough.

Comment: uname -a on fedora 19:
    Linux hostname 3.11.4-201.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 10 14:11:18 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

the kernel of fedora has the fedora version embedded in the filename as you can see :) will rerun this command after upgrading to fedora 20 (fedup is running atm, will report back afterwards if the kernel filename changed or not)

Comment: Linux hostname 3.11.4-301.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 10 15:09:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

thats the output of uname -a after running fedup-cli to update to fedora 20.

Answer (score 6):

```
[Belmiro@HP-550 ~]$ uname -a

Linux HP-550 2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Feb 11 07:06:34 UTC 2010
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


[Belmiro@HP-550 ~]$ lsb_release -a

LSB Version: :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:deskt
op-3.1-amd64:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-amd64:desktop-3.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description: Fedora release 11 (Leonidas)
Release: 11
Codename: Leonidas
[Belmiro@HP-550 ~]$
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply run this command to get the version number:

```
rpm -E %fedora
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On my installation of Fedora 25 (workstation) all of the distribution ID info was found in this file:

```
/usr/lib/os.release.d/os-release-workstation
```

This included,

- NAME=Fedora
- VERSION="25 (Workstation Edition)"
- ID=fedora
- VERSION_ID=25
- PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 25 (Workstation Edition)"
- <...>
- VARIANT="Workstation Edition"
- VARIANT_ID=workstation

Answer (score 0):

uname -a works with my fc11

Answer (score 0):

`cat /etc/os-release`

Works both on Fedora and Silverblue.

Answer (score -1):

use commmand ,  screenfetch
output format info.

Comment: Please give a little more details to your solution.